# ASP.NET MVC Core 3.0 - Why API Request from body keeps returning !ModelState.IsValid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently using `ASP.NET MVC Core 3.0` to create an API project. I was successful to send a POST request without parameter. But currently I'm having a problem when trying to send a POST request with the parameter in JSON via Postman, always getting invalid request as shown below.

[image]

Notice that there's also `key` param in the query string to authorize the request using the middleware I created. This part has no problem.

Here's the code of the controller:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] UserRequest model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(new ApiResponse(400, "Model state is not valid."));

        return Ok($"Hello world, {model.Id}!");
    }
}
```

The odd thing is, I've already created and used the class UserRequest as a parameter input, as shown below:

```
public class UserRequest
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my `Startup.cs` settings, I've already added `AddNewtonsoftJson` to enable JSON serializer input:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

    /*Other API, DB settings and services goes here*/
    ...
}
```

Here's my attempts so far:

1. Added `[BindProperties]` on `UserRequest` class. Still returning same error.
2. Removed `[FromBody]` on the parameter of controller. Still returning same error.
3. Renamed `id` to `Id` to follow the naming inside `UserRequest` class. Still returning same error.
4. Added this code on `Startup.cs`, this will execute `return BadRequest(new ApiResponse(400, "Model state is not valid."));`:

   ```
   .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
   {
       options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
   })
   ```
5. Removed this code on `Startup.cs`

   ```
   .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
   ```

   It will return this instead:

   ```
   {
       "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
       "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
       "status": 400,
       "traceId": "|f6037d12-44fa46ceaffd3dba.",
       "errors": {
           "$": [
               "The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
           ]
       }
   }
   ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated 12/11/2019: Here's how I handle the API key request:**

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IApiKeyService apiKeyService)
{
    var remoteIpAddress = httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

    if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Request from {remoteIpAddress}.");

        var queryString = httpContext.Request.Query;
        queryString.TryGetValue("key", out var keyValue);

        if (keyValue.ToString().Any(char.IsWhiteSpace))
            keyValue = keyValue.ToString().Replace(" ", "+");

        if (httpContext.Request.Method != "POST")
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status405MethodNotAllowed;
            await WriteJsonResponseAsync(httpContext, "Only POST method is allowed.");
            return;
        }

        if (keyValue.Count == 0)
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
            await WriteJsonResponseAsync(httpContext, "API Key is missing.");
            return;
        }

        var isKeyValid = await apiKeyService.IsApiKeyValidAsync(keyValue);
        var isKeyActive = await apiKeyService.IsApiKeyActiveAsync(keyValue);

        if (!isKeyValid)
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            await WriteJsonResponseAsync(httpContext, "Invalid API Key.");
            return;
        }

        if (!isKeyActive)
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status406NotAcceptable;
            await WriteJsonResponseAsync(httpContext, "Service is Deactivated.");
            return;
        }
    }
    await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
}

private static async Task WriteJsonResponseAsync(HttpContext httpContext, string message = null)
{
    httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    var response = new ApiResponse(httpContext.Response.StatusCode, message);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
    await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(json);
}
```

Comment: It seems to work for me. Maybe it is something to do with the `key` value you are passing? How is that handled by your code?

Comment: @SimplyGed, updated my question. See above.

Comment: A simple way to get the validation error in your code is to comment out the `ApiController` attribute on your controller class. This is doing the validation before it gets to your code and returning the error you see. If you comment it out then it should reach your class and you can more easily determine what is wrong

Comment: Do you have any other custom middleware? The error indicates your are deserializing the request body but not resetting the stream position back to 0 before passing it on

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#automatic-http-400-responses

Comment: I do have another middleware, but it's just to log the request and response. Also I tried to comment out the `ApiController`, it will give the result as point (4), where request is `null`

Comment: Logging the request and response might be causing the problem. If you are calling something like `await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();` you need to reset the body back to the start using `request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Comment: And the same in the response `response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Comment: @SimplyGed, thank you very much for your help! The problem was indeed because of missing `request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` when logging the request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed in the comments your logging middleware is causing the problem.
When you read the request body, or response body, you need to reset the stream so that other middleware can read it (in this case the JsonSerializer).

In your logging middleware you will have a call like:

```
var body = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
```

Before the method returns you need to reset that stream:

```
request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

This is the same for the response code e.g.

```
response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

**EDIT**

As requested in the comments here is an example of what the middleware code might be:

```
public class LoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public LoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.EnableBuffering();
        var body = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        // Log the contents of body...

        context.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

The code to reset the `Body` stream position needs to come before the call to `_next(context)`

Comment: I am currently facing this issue. I am not sure if this answer is clear enough. Which method are you referring to by "Before the method returns", I have created and used my middleware so far. Can you perhaps include the answer you provided and position it on the code that is provided on the original question?

Comment: @MosiaThabo Added some example code for you. Hope it helps!

Comment: I washaving the same problem. But I do not have any logging or another custom middleware, just a base ASP.NET Core 3.1 web API project. I had only one class with mixed body and query string parameters, by separating them into two classes, one for body content and other for query string, the problem was solved.

Comment: I had the request body empty in my controller, I tried EVERYTHING but nothing helped. I commented out the part where I read the body and it helped!! Tnx!