# ASP .NET Core Integration Tests fails with corrupted body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on a project where we have to develop a web API with ASP .NET Core 3.x. So far, so good, it is running well. Now, I'm writing some integration tests for this web API and I have some trouble to get the tests for everything else than GET request to work.

We're using the Clean Architecture from Jason Taylor. This means we have a core project with all our request handler, a domain project with all database entities and a presentation project for the API controllers. We use [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) and dependency injection for the communication between these projects.

Now, we have the problem that the body data of the reuqest doesn't reach the controller.

This is how the Update method in the controller looks like:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public abstract class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    private IMediator _mediator;
    protected IMediator Mediator => _mediator ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>();
}

public class FavoriteController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(long id, UpdateFavoriteCommand command)
    {
        if (command == null || id != command.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        // Sends the request to the corresponding IRequestHandler
        await Mediator.Send(command);

        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

We use xUnit.net as test framework.
For the integration tests, we're using an InMemory SQLite database which is setup in a fixture class.

The test looks like the following:

```cs
public class UpdateFavoritesTestSqlite : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactoryWithInMemorySqlite<Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactoryWithInMemorySqlite<Startup> _factory;
    private readonly string _endpoint;

    public UpdateFavoritesTestSqlite(WebApplicationFactoryWithInMemorySqlite<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _endpoint = "api/Favorite/Update/";
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task UpdateFavoriteDetail_WithFullUpdate_ShouldUpdateCorrectly()
    {
        // Arange
        var client = _factory.CreateClient(); // WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient()
        var command = new UpdateFavoriteCommand
        {
            Id = 5,
            Caption = "caption new",
            FavoriteName = "a new name",
            Public = true
        };

        // Convert to JSON
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command);
        var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var stringUri = client.BaseAddress + _endpoint + command.Id;
        var uri = new Uri(stringUri);

        // Act
        var response = await client.PutAsync(uri, httpContent); 
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        httpContent.Dispose();

        // Assert
        response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);

    }
}
```

If we run the test, we get an 400 Bad Request error.
If we run the test in Debug mode, we can see that the code throws a custom ValidationException because of a model state error. This is configured in the DependencyInjection of the presentation project:

```cs
services
    .AddControllers()
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
        {
            var failures = context.ModelState.Keys
                .Where(k => ModelValidationState.Invalid.Equals(context.ModelState[k].ValidationState))
                .ToDictionary(k => k, k => (IEnumerable<string>)context.ModelState[k].Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToList());

            throw new ValidationException(failures);
        };
    })
    .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<IWebApiDbContext>());
```

The failures object contains one error which says:

```
The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
```

Here is a screenshot: [Visual Studio in Debugging mode with json error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUeiI.jpg)

In one article in stackoverflow I've read, that removing the `[ApiController]` class attribute can result in a more detailed error description. During debugging again the test and setting a breakpoint int the Update method from the FavoriteController at the line with `await Mediator.Send(command);`, I was able to see, that the command object arriving the Update method contains only null or default values, except the id, which was 5.

```
command 
    Caption         null    string
    FavoriteName    null    string
    Id              5       long
    Public          false   bool
```

The most confusing (and frustrating) part is, that a manual test with swagger or postman are both successfull. The way I understand it, there has to be a problem during the integration test.

I hope, someone can help me and see what I'm missing. Could it be possible that there is something wrong with the HttpClient of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found the problem in our LoggingMiddleware of the web api presentation project.
Before writing this question, we already hat a look at another article on stackoverflow:
[ASP.NET MVC Core 3.0 - Why API Request from body keeps returning !ModelState.IsValid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812020/asp-net-mvc-core-3-0-why-api-request-from-body-keeps-returning-modelstate-isv)
But we already had the `request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` in our code. So, we thought that's it and it couldn't be the problem.

But now, we've found this article:
[.net core 3.0 logging middleware by pipereader](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5251458/net-core-3-0-logging-middleware-by-pipereader)

Instead of reading the request body like this:

```cs
await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

... where the stream is closed after read, we're using now the BodyReader as a stream and leave the stream open:

```cs
var stream = request.BodyReader.AsStream(true); // AsStream(true) to let stream open
await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```