# The input does not contain any JSON tokens

Tags: c#, middleware, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-middleware

I am getting below error due to my middleware

> The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

Below is my Middleware

```
public class HttpLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public HttpLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = await GetRequestAsTextAsync(context.Request);
        var logFlag = !(request.Contains("index.html") || request.Contains("swagger.json"));
        #region Request Logging
        if (logFlag)
        {
            Logger.WriteUsage(request);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Response Logging
        var bodyStream = context.Response.Body;
        var responseBodyStream = new MemoryStream();
        context.Response.Body = responseBodyStream;

        await _next(context);

        if (context.Response.Body.CanSeek)
        {
            responseBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var responseBody = new StreamReader(responseBodyStream).ReadToEnd();
            if (logFlag)
            {
                Logger.WriteUsage(responseBody + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            responseBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        }
        await responseBodyStream.CopyToAsync(bodyStream);
        #endregion
    }


    private async Task<string> GetRequestAsTextAsync(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var body = request.Body;

        //Set the reader for the request back at the beginning of its stream.
        request.EnableBuffering();

        //Read request stream
        var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];

        //Copy into  buffer.
        //await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        var stream = request.BodyReader.AsStream(true); // AsStream(true) to let stream open
        await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        //Convert the byte[] into a string using UTF8 encoding...
        var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        //Assign the read body back to the request body
        request.Body = body;

        return $"{request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {request.QueryString} {bodyAsText}";
    }

    private async Task<string> GetResponseAsTextAsync(HttpResponse response)
    {
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        //Create stream reader to write entire stream
        var text = await new StreamReader(response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return text;
    }
}
```

This middleware meant to log both request and response of api but i am not able to post anything now in post api, every time i post a json i get above error.
Found few post regarding this

[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812020/asp-net-mvc-core-3-0-why-api-request-from-body-keeps-returning-modelstate-isv)

If i comment out request reading part than everything works out but that mean no logging.

Can anybody some solution here , i am using .net core 3.1 web api project

Answer (score 2):

You should not  set the value of "request.Body" with "body".
if you don't want to change the requestbody,you could just delet the codes
if you do want to modify your request body in the middleware,you could try the codes below:

```
var RequestBody = new StreamReader(request.BodyReader.AsStream()).ReadToEnd();//read from body
byte[] content1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RequestBody.Replace("string", "NoString"));//repalce the "string"
var bodyAsText = Encoding.Default.GetString(content1);
var requestBodyStream = new MemoryStream();//create a stream
requestBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
requestBodyStream.Write(content1, 0, content1.Length);
request.Body = requestBodyStream;//save the repalcement to Body
request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

The Result:
[image]
[image]